# logitech unifying receiver input lag / completely unresponsive

Tags: logitech-unifying

20.04 updated.

I have a Logitech keyboard and mouse connected via Unifying Receiver. Until recently this has been working flawlessly.

Lately either mouse or keyboard or sometimes both, fail to respond. Sometimes after a lag the display will update with all the keystrokes previously entered.

Sometimes restarting the device will repair the connection.

`fwupdmgr` says that firmware is up to date.

`Solaar` tells me both devices have good battery status.

An unpair/pair restart will usually work to restore functionality but sometimes I need a full system restart.

I have tried switching USB ports.

I have tried moving the receiver right next to the keyboard using a USB extension.

I have tried placing my phone far away.

What else to try?

```
top -b -n1 | head -50

top - 15:35:29 up  8:56,  1 user,  load average: 0.89, 1.14, 1.27
Tasks: 306 total,   1 running, 304 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 15.3 us,  6.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 77.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15873.6 total,   7201.2 free,   1601.0 used,   7071.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.  13799.3 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   2976 stephen   20   0  434272  48072  26296 S   6.7   0.3   7:22.00 command+
 730817 stephen   20   0  809024  48284  39020 S   6.7   0.3   0:01.48 mate-te+
      1 root      20   0  169208  13272   8280 S   0.0   0.1   0:03.76 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par+
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_perc+
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.57 ksoftir+
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:22.66 rcu_sch+
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.42 migrati+
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.57 migrati+
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.23 ksoftir+
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2
     22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+
     23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.59 migrati+
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 ksoftir+
     26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3
     28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+
     29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.53 migrati+
     30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.14 ksoftir+
     32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
     33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/4
     34 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+
     35 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.52 migrati+
     36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.13 ksoftir+
     38 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
     39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/5
     40 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+
     41 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.53 migrati+
     42 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.75 ksoftir+
     44 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
     45 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/6
     46 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_in+
     47 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.55 migrati+
     48 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.17 ksoftir+
     50 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker+
```

======

```
    free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.7Gi       7.0Gi       142Mi       6.9Gi        13Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

====

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 10
```

====

```
ps auxc | grep -i therm
root         178  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   May05   0:00 
acpi_thermal_pm
root         898  0.0  0.0 125856  9864 ?        Ssl  May05   0:09 thermald
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and a screenshot of `top` when the system is idle.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`. Make sure to let me know when this is done, by sending me a comment that starts with @heynnema, else I'll miss your updates, like I did this one. Please respond to your temp question also.

Comment: @heynnema Done. Sorry about yesterday. I had set up a comment to notify you then realised I had one more bit to do. Then I didn't get back to the comment. I am still getting info on the temp problem. It looks like a browser overload but need a bit more evidence.

Comment: Since you have acpi_thermal_pm, you should uninstall thermald... that might even be your problem. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema       Why might that be a problem?

Comment: @heynnema THIS is the question about logitech receiver. Are you answering my other question -- about overheating CPU -- on *this* question.  I'm confused. Perhaps we should roll back on these comments here and move them to that other question? To avoid confusing others. I know you are well-meaning but... unless I'm mistaken and thermald has something to do with the logitech problem,  we should correct the public record

Comment: No, my comment was directed at this question. You seem to have so many problems with your computer, they may overlap. Because you have TWO processes trying to handle temp control, they overlap, and thermald has 8+ idle_inject processes running on your system. If temps climb high enough, thermald will bump up those processes to the top of your `top` list, and start throttling your CPU's, and possibly effect various response times... like the Logitech.

Comment: @heynnema Ah I see. Thank you. This particular machine gives me problems that my others do not. Perhaps this will help. I have removed `thermald`, rebooted, and now let's see.

Comment: @heynnema With thermald removed, still getting the temperature issue and the input lag.

Comment: Go over to your temp question, and answer my info request there. What OS/version is this?

Comment: Just for reference, this is not specific to Linux. The problem also occurs on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Move the Unifying Receiver to a different USB port. I found that was required to enable solid connections from my Logitech devices.

Comment: One of the things I had tried  but it wasn't a help. Thanks though. I'll add to the question.

Comment: Works sometimes but temporarily. Same effect as replugging the receiver into the same port -- works sometimes and temporarily. 

Ongoing problem...